# jQuery clone - resulting cloned controls don't function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Working on asp.net/mvc5 website.

I have a pop up modal dialog (MVC 5 partial page) which is supposed to be used for advanced filtering for a data table. I wanted the user to be able to add or delete as many filtering "items"/rows as possible. The filter controls are on a row with a class "filter_row". Here's the modal body code....

```
          <div class="modal-body" style="height: 300px;">
                <div class="row filter_row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="checkbox i-checks inline-block">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="">
                        </div> &nbsp;
                        <select data-placeholder="Choose..." class="chosen-select" style="width: 150px;">
                            <option value="">First Name</option>
                            <option value="">Last Name</option>
                            <option value="">DOB</option>
                            <option value="">SSN</option>
                            <option value="">City</option>
                            <option value="">State</option>
                            <option value="">Zip</option>
                            <option value="">Account</option>
                        </select>
                        &nbsp;
                        <input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control inline-block" style="width: 200px;">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('.filter_row_clone').remove();"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

When I click the add button (+) the row is supposed to be duplicated and it is. This part works fine. (See image below, where I clicked (+) a few times.) ***The problem is that I cannot click on or use any of the cloned controls.*** Here's a screenshot. In this screenshot only row 1, the original row, is clickable.

[image: Only row 1 is clickable]

Here's the code for my "add" button in the header....

```
<a href="#" onclick="addRow();">
    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

Here's the main function addRow.... (SEE UPDATED CODE BELOW)

```
    function addRow() {
    $(".filter_row").clone(true, true).removeClass("filter_row").addClass("filter_row_clone").insertAfter("div.filter_row:last");
};
```

(The reason I removed the main "filter_row" class (during clone) is that each time I clicked the button it was adding too many rows after the first click.)

FYI: The checkbox is using iCheck plugin and dropdown is using chosen plugin. On the main parent form (from which this MVC partial page (modal) is called) I reference the necessary scripts and styles.

Thanks!

**** UPDATE ****

So, the partial page above is basically used as a modal pop up. The "parent" page has this code. (This code works and the effects are applied correctly to the plugins, but not the cloned ones.)

```
       $('#AdvancedSearch')
        .on('shown.bs.modal',
            function (e) {
                // the custom checkbox plugin
                $('.i-checks').iCheck({
                    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
                    radioClass: 'iradio_square-green'
                });

                // the "chosen" plugins
                $(".chosen-select").chosen({
                    disable_search_threshold: 10,
                    no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"
                });

            });
```

Using the suggestion below (thanks @StephenMuecke) here's my new addRow() function....

```
<script>
function addRow() {
    $(".filter_row").clone(true, true).first().insertAfter("div.filter_row:last");
    $('.chosen-select').last().chosen(
        {
            disable_search_threshold: 10,
            no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"
        }
    );
    $('.chosen-select').last().chosen();
    $('.i-checks').last().iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
        radioClass: 'iradio_square-green'
    });
};
</script>
```

For the cloned controls, I can now use all cloned controls except for the dropdown. When I click on the dropdown the original one on the first row opens up...

[image: cloned controls]

Comment: You need to give more information about the original html and how you attach the plugin. There is no reason to change the class name - you could have just used `$(".filter_row").first().clone();` but you also need to attach the plugin to the newly created elements.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks. +1 for your .first() reference. Thanks! Isn't the fact that the checkbox and dropdown appear styled show the plugins are attached? I"m just not able to check the checkbox or select from dropdownlist. Can you be more specific? I'll add the modalbody code to my code above too. Thanks again!

Comment: @StephenMuecke I removed the plugin class for the checkbox and dropdown and I was able to use the controls. So that seems to be the issue. How can I "attach the plugin" then?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Maybe it's a problem because the cloned controls do not have unique IDs so maybe the plugin code is always using the original control(s)?

Comment: We need to see how you currently attach the plugins to your elements. You don't need unique `id's`, but you do need to attach the plugins to the newly added elements - e.g. something like `$('.chosen-select').last().chosen({ ... });` after the element has been added.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks. Please see the updated code in my op. Added code that is invoked by parent form to apply plugin effects the first time, which works.

Comment: @StephenMuecke using your (nice) suggestion now the checkbox works fine. But I still can't click on the cloned dropdownlist with the "chosen" plugin. When I click on it the original dropdownlist opens up.

Comment: I ended up just removing the dropdownlist. Everything seems to be working fine now. The main issue was re-attaching the plugins to the elements as @StephenMuecke mentioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I don't know if this is what you want. Let me know after you test it.

```
<a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" id="test" aria-hidden="true">Button</i>
</a>
<div class="row filter_row"> 
    <select class="" name="txtCategory[]" id="category1">
       <option value="">Option 1</option>
       <option value="">Option 2</option>
       <option value="">Option 3</option>
       <option value="">Option 4</option>
    </select>
</div>



$("#test").on("click", clone);

function clone(){
  $(".filter_row").clone(true, true).removeClass("filter_row").addClass("filter_row_clone").insertAfter("div.filter_row:last");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7gddtnee/

Comment: Thanks. Your jsfiddle seems to work. What exactly is different about your code? Are my iCheck or chosen plugins somehow failing it? I don't think so because they are styled correctly. Just not able to click on it. Thanks again!  I'll add the modalbody code to my comments above too.

Comment: You are doing the onClick on the "a" button and I' doing the onClick on the script, I think it can be the part failing because when I tested your code I coppied the a button and It didn't do the function.